# Building a custom state space model using Statsmodels MLEmodel

Tags: python, time-series

I am studying how to build a custom model of state space model using state space model in python.
I was wondering if I should use the MLEmodel class of statsomdels at the URL below, but I am not sure how to build it.
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.MLEModel.html
https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_custom_models.html#Model-1:-time-varying-coefficients

Specifically, I would like to make a long-term forecast using the following model.

1.Equation of state

x_t = x_{t-1} + A exp(B / z_{t-1}) + E_{1t}

- x_t : state at time t
- x_{t-1} : state at time t-1
- A : constant(parameter to estimate)
- B : constant(parameter to estimate)
- z_{t-1} : explanatory variable
- E_{1t} : system noise(~ N(0,u_1))

2. Observation equation
   y_t = x_t + E_{2t}

- y_t : observation data(sensing)
- E_{2t} : observation noise(~ N(0,u_2))

Please tell me

Answer (score 0):

A basic implementation of your model is (**edited** to add methods required for forecasting):

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

class RWD(sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel):
    param_names = ['A', 'B', 'u_1', 'u_2']
    start_params = [1., 0., 1., 1]

    def __init__(self, endog, exog):
        exog = np.squeeze(exog)
        super().__init__(endog, exog=exog, k_states=1, initialization='diffuse')
        self.k_exog = 1
        
        # Z = I
        self['design', 0, 0] = 1.
        # T = I
        self['transition', 0, 0] = 1.
        # R = I
        self['selection', 0, 0] = 1.
        
        # Set c_t to be time-varying
        self['state_intercept'] = np.zeros((1, self.nobs))
        
    def clone(self, endog, exog, **kwargs):
        # This method must be set to allow forecasting in custom
        # state space models that include time-varying state
        # space matrices, like we have for state_intercept here
        return self._clone_from_init_kwds(endog, exog=exog, **kwargs)
        
    def transform_params(self, params):
        # Variances must be positive
        params[2:] = params[2:]**2
        return params
        
    def untransform_params(self, params):
        # Reverse of above transformation
        params[2:] = params[2:]**0.5
        return params
    
    def update(self, params, **kwargs):
        params = super().update(params, **kwargs)
        
        # c_t = A * exp(B / z_t)
        self['state_intercept', 0, :] = params[0] * np.exp(params[1] / self.exog)
        
        # H = u_1
        self['obs_cov', 0, 0] = params[2]
        # Q = u_2
        self['state_cov', 0, 0] = params[3]
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Fulton!
I am very honored to hear from the developers directly.

Comment: No problem, I hope it's useful.

Comment: I'm sorry. Mr.Fulton

I would like to add a constant term T to the equation I was supposed to, as shown below. Should I change the specification method of 'transition'?

Comment: Mr. Fulton. Please tell me.
Is it possible to increase the number of lags in a custom state space model?
(t-2, t-3, t-4, t-5,,,,)

@cfulton

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. Mr.Fulton

I would like to add a constant term T to the equation I was supposed to, as shown below.
Should I change the specification method of 'transition'?

Equation of state:
x_t = T x_{t-1} + A exp(B / z_{t-1}) + E_{1t}

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

class RWD(sm.tsa.statespace.MLEModel):
    param_names = ['T', 'A', 'B', 'u_1', 'u_2']
    start_params = [1., 1., 0., 1., 1]

    def __init__(self, endog, exog):
        exog = np.squeeze(exog)
        super().__init__(endog, exog=exog, k_states=1, initialization='diffuse')
        self.k_exog = 1
        
        # Z = I
        self['design', 0, 0] = 1.
        # T = I
        #self['transition', 0, 0] = 1.
        # R = I
        self['selection', 0, 0] = 1.
        
        # Set c_t to be time-varying
        self['state_intercept'] = np.zeros((1, self.nobs))
        
    def clone(self, endog, exog, **kwargs):
        #This method must be set to allow forecasting in custom
        #state space models that include time-varying state
        #space matrices, like we have for state_intercept here
        return self._clone_from_init_kwds(endog, exog=exog, **kwargs)
        
    def transform_params(self, params):
        # Variances must be positive
        params[3:] = params[3:]**2
        return params
        
    def untransform_params(self, params):
        # Reverse of above transformation
        params[3:] = params[3:]**0.5
        return params
    
    def update(self, params, **kwargs):
        params = super().update(params, **kwargs)
        # T = T
        self['transition', 0, 0] = params[0] 
        # c_t = A * exp(B / z_t)
        self['state_intercept', 0, :] = params[1] * np.exp(params[2] / self.exog)
        
        # H = u_1
        self['obs_cov', 0, 0] = params[3]
        # Q = u_2
        self['state_cov', 0, 0] = params[4]
```